# passing a database value using response.redirect

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, response.redirect

```
<body>
   <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@page import="javax.sql.*" %>
    <%
        String user=request.getParameter("username");
        session.putValue("uname",user);
        String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaproject","root","");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from university where username='"+user+"'");
        if(rs.next())
        {
            if(rs.getString(3).equals(pass))
            {
                              response.sendRedirect("Uuserprofile.jsp?id=<%=rs.getString("id")%>");

            }
```

netbeans ide says ')' unclosed string literal but i dont understand where its missing

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
response.sendRedirect("Uuserprofile.jsp?id=<%=rs.getString("id")%>");
```

to this:

```
response.sendRedirect("Uuserprofile.jsp?id="<%=rs.getString("id")%>);
```

Comment: Put inverted comma just before id=